# Writing functions using TensorFlow

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

So I am very new to TensorFlow so my question might be a little stupid or obvious. So I wrote a small and simple code in TensorFlow using function. So basically I am reading 1000 parameters and storing it in a numpy array and passing it through a NN with 2 hidden layers. Here is my code:

```html
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import random


pc = open("../data/pcNum.txt", 'r') 
npc = open("../data/npcNum.txt", 'r')
lines1 = pc.readlines()
lines2 = npc.readlines()

size = 200
learning_rate = 0.01
epochs = 200

trainDataset = np.array([])
labels = np.array([])
trainList = []

def arrayfy(sequence):
    seq = np.array([])
    for i in range(0, len(sequence)):
        seq = np.append(seq, int(sequence[i]))
    return seq

for i in range(0, size):
    sequence = lines1[i].strip()
    trainList.append((sequence, 1))
    sequence = lines2[i].strip()
    trainList.append((sequence, 0))

random.shuffle(trainList)

for i in trainList:
    seq = arrayfy(i[0])
    trainDataset = np.append(trainDataset, seq)
    if(i[1] == 0):
        label = np.array([0, 1])
    else:
        label = np.array([1, 0])
    labels = np.append(labels, label)
    

trainDataset = trainDataset.reshape((2 * size, 1000))
trainDataset = trainDataset.T
labels = np.transpose(labels.reshape((-1, 2)))

dataset = np.asarray(trainDataset, np.float32)
labels = np.asarray(labels, np.float32)
dataset = tf.convert_to_tensor(dataset, tf.float32)
#labels = tf.convert_to_tensor(labels, tf.float32)

# Begining of TensorFlow code

l1_nodes = 100
l2_nodes = 100
out_nodes = 2

weights_l1 = tf.get_variable('weights_l1', dtype = tf.float32, initializer = tf.random_normal((1000, l1_nodes), mean = 0.0, stddev = 1.0))
weights_l2 = tf.get_variable('weights_l2', dtype = tf.float32, initializer = tf.random_normal((l1_nodes, l2_nodes), mean = 0.0, stddev = 1.0))
weights_out = tf.get_variable('weights_out', dtype = tf.float32, initializer = tf.random_normal((l2_nodes, 2), mean = 0.0, stddev = 1.0))

bias_l1 = tf.get_variable('bias_l1', dtype = tf.float32, initializer = tf.constant(0.0))
bias_l2 = tf.get_variable('bias_l2', dtype = tf.float32, initializer = tf.constant(0.0))
bias_out = tf.get_variable('bias_out', dtype = tf.float32, initializer = tf.constant(0.0))

"""a1 = tf.placeholder(dtype = tf.float32, name = 'a1')
a2 = tf.placeholder(dtype = tf.float32, name = 'a2')
z_out = tf.placeholder(dtype = tf.float32, name = 'z_out')
hypothesis = tf.placeholder(dtype = tf.float32, name = 'hypothesis')"""



def forwardPropagation(dataset, weights_l1, bias_l1, weights_l2, bias_l2, weights_out, bias_out):
    a1 = tf.sigmoid(tf.tensordot(tf.transpose(weights_l1), dataset, axes = 1) + bias_l1)
    a2 = tf.sigmoid(tf.tensordot(tf.transpose(weights_l2), a1, axes = 1) + bias_l2)
    z_out = tf.tensordot(tf.transpose(weights_out), a2, axes = 1) + bias_out
    return z_out


entropy = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2(logits = z_out, labels = labels, name = 'cross_entropy')
loss = tf.reduce_mean(entropy, name = 'loss')


optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(loss)

hypothesis = tf.nn.softmax(z_out)
correct_preds = tf.equal(tf.argmax(hypothesis, 0), tf.argmax(labels, 0))
accuracy = tf.reduce_sum(tf.cast(correct_preds, tf.float32))

writer = tf.summary.FileWriter('./graphs/logreg', tf.get_default_graph())
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    for i in range(0, epochs):
        z_out = sess.run(forwardPropagation(dataset, weights_l1, bias_l1, weights_l2, bias_l2, weights_out, bias_out))
        _, l = sess.run([optimizer, loss])                 #, feed_dict = {z_out:z_out, labels:labels})
        sess.run(hypothesis)
        sess.run(correct_preds)
        acc = sess.run(accuracy)
        print("Epoch :", i+1, ", loss : ", l, ", accuracy :", acc)
writer.close()
```

It gives the error as:

`entropy = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2(logits = z_out, labels = labels, name = 'cross_entropy')
NameError: name 'z_out' is not defined`

So what do I have to do to make this run properly keeping the function?

Also when I remove the function it apparently runs although I am not sure whether it is doing what I expect it to do:

```html
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import random


pc = open("../data/pcNum.txt", 'r') 
npc = open("../data/npcNum.txt", 'r')
lines1 = pc.readlines()
lines2 = npc.readlines()

size = 200
learning_rate = 0.01
epochs = 200

trainDataset = np.array([])
labels = np.array([])
trainList = []

def arrayfy(sequence):
    seq = np.array([])
    for i in range(0, len(sequence)):
        seq = np.append(seq, int(sequence[i]))
    return seq

for i in range(0, size):
    sequence = lines1[i].strip()
    trainList.append((sequence, 1))
    sequence = lines2[i].strip()
    trainList.append((sequence, 0))

random.shuffle(trainList)

for i in trainList:
    seq = arrayfy(i[0])
    trainDataset = np.append(trainDataset, seq)
    if(i[1] == 0):
        label = np.array([0, 1])
    else:
        label = np.array([1, 0])
    labels = np.append(labels, label)
    

trainDataset = trainDataset.reshape((2 * size, 1000))
trainDataset = trainDataset.T
labels = np.transpose(labels.reshape((-1, 2)))

dataset = np.asarray(trainDataset, np.float32)
labels = np.asarray(labels, np.float32)
dataset = tf.convert_to_tensor(dataset, tf.float32)
#labels = tf.convert_to_tensor(labels, tf.float32)


l1_nodes = 100
l2_nodes = 100
out_nodes = 2

weights_l1 = tf.get_variable('weights_l1', dtype = tf.float32, initializer = tf.random_normal((1000, l1_nodes), mean = 0.0, stddev = 1.0))
weights_l2 = tf.get_variable('weights_l2', dtype = tf.float32, initializer = tf.random_normal((l1_nodes, l2_nodes), mean = 0.0, stddev = 1.0))
weights_out = tf.get_variable('weights_out', dtype = tf.float32, initializer = tf.random_normal((l2_nodes, 2), mean = 0.0, stddev = 1.0))

bias_l1 = tf.get_variable('bias_l1', dtype = tf.float32, initializer = tf.constant(0.0))
bias_l2 = tf.get_variable('bias_l2', dtype = tf.float32, initializer = tf.constant(0.0))
bias_out = tf.get_variable('bias_out', dtype = tf.float32, initializer = tf.constant(0.0))

"""a1 = tf.placeholder(dtype = tf.float32, name = 'a1')
a2 = tf.placeholder(dtype = tf.float32, name = 'a2')
z_out = tf.placeholder(dtype = tf.float32, name = 'z_out')
hypothesis = tf.placeholder(dtype = tf.float32, name = 'hypothesis')"""



#def forwardPropagation(dataset, weights_l1, bias_l1, weights_l2, bias_l2, weights_out, bias_out):
a1 = tf.sigmoid(tf.tensordot(tf.transpose(weights_l1), dataset, axes = 1) + bias_l1)
a2 = tf.sigmoid(tf.tensordot(tf.transpose(weights_l2), a1, axes = 1) + bias_l2)
z_out = tf.tensordot(tf.transpose(weights_out), a2, axes = 1) + bias_out
#return z_out


entropy = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2(logits = z_out, labels = labels, name = 'cross_entropy')
loss = tf.reduce_mean(entropy, name = 'loss')


optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(loss)

hypothesis = tf.nn.softmax(z_out)
correct_preds = tf.equal(tf.argmax(hypothesis, 0), tf.argmax(labels, 0))
accuracy = tf.reduce_sum(tf.cast(correct_preds, tf.float32))

writer = tf.summary.FileWriter('./graphs/logreg', tf.get_default_graph())
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    for i in range(0, epochs):
        #z_out = sess.run(forwardPropagation(dataset, weights_l1, bias_l1, weights_l2, bias_l2, weights_out, bias_out))
        _, l = sess.run([optimizer, loss])                 #, feed_dict = {z_out:z_out, labels:labels})
        sess.run(hypothesis)
        sess.run(correct_preds)
        acc = sess.run(accuracy)
        print("Epoch :", i+1, ", loss : ", l, ", accuracy :", acc)
writer.close()
```

Any help and tips is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your entropy calculation is called trying to use `z_out` as a parameter before you've initialized the variable.  In the first code you have the following line assigning a value to `z_out`, but you've commented out the code.

```
z_out = tf.placeholder(dtype = tf.float32, name = 'z_out')
```

Next you have your function `forwardPropagation` that returns a value for `z_out`, but you do not call the `forwardPropagation` function until the very end of the code.  Then in the next line you're trying to calculate the `entropy` using the `z_out` variable that has not been initialized, which is why you're getting an error.

Your second set of code works because you are performing the `z_out` calculation before calculating `entropy`.  To get the first set of code to work you must call `forwardPropagation` to define `z_out` before you calculate `entropy`.

Comment: Thanks...I'll one question..If I hadn't commented it out would it have worked?

Comment: Apparently it is saying no gradients provided...Even though I call the function before running optimizer?

Comment: In your first section of code if you call `forwardPropagation()` prior to when you calculate `entropy` it should be the same as your second set of code.

Comment: Hmmm...I figured it out but apparently my output labels are all 0's but yet showing a high accuracy